# Vue JS mutating prop with Alert component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using VueStrap components based on: https://wffranco.github.io/vue-strap/
Unfortunately I receive an error while I am setting visibility for alert, my code:

HTML:

```
<alert :show="showAlert" placement="top-right" :duration=3000 v-bind:type="alertType" style="height:90px; min-width:380px;" dismissable>
      <span class="icon">
        <i style="font-size: xx-large;" class="fa fa-check-circle" v-if="alertType==='info'"></i>
        <i style="font-size: xx-large;" class="fa fa-info-circle" v-if="alertType==='danger'"></i>
        <i style="font-size: xx-large;" class="fa fa-check-circle" v-if="alertType==='success'"></i>
      </span>
      <div class="alertContent">
        <strong v-if="alertType==='success'">Success</strong>
        <strong v-if="alertType==='danger'">Error</strong>
        <p v-html="AlertInside"></p>
      </div>
</alert>
```

While i am binding :show based on showAlert everything works fine but i receive an error that "

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "show" found in --->Alert>

I have tried v-model, :show.sync but vmodel doesnt work at all and .sync doesnt make any difference.

On github there is info that vue js 2.1.x is required but I have seen somewhere post that someone had simillar problem while using vue 1.0. 
My current vue version is 2.5.16

I search for solution for a while and i couldnt get any proper answers, please help ;)

Comment: the alert component must be trying to change the value of 'showAlert'. It should be emitting something like 'alertClosed' at which point you could set 'showAlert' to false in the parent component. Not sure by what you've given if that manipulation is just an problem in vuestrap, or whether you're manipulating that 'show' prop in the alert component somehow, but that's what the warning seems to be indicating.

Answer (score 0):

So as @Jayem163 mentioned this alert occurs while I am trying to update child component alert variable show.
I occurs that this problem was in VueStrap component and after dismissing alert something like this happened :

```
watch: {
    show(val) {
      if (this._timeout) clearTimeout(this._timeout)
      if (val && Boolean(this.duration)) {
        this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          this.show = false; ---> this i changed to :this.$emit('update:show', false ); AND IT WORKS WITHOUT ERROR :)
        }, this.duration)
      }
    }
  }
```